# Closing Angular material Dialog while using ngForm?

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material, angular-forms

How do I close a dialog if I am using `ngForm`?  I have two dialogs used before this one pops up and I understand you get the data use `[mat-dialog-close]="true"` and then use `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` for example.  But on this last one I use `ngForm` so that I can use the data submitted which I eventually run through a `.filter()` to create a new array. Then with this array I use a service to send it to my other component where I use the array  and `.map()` it to make a `geojson` leaflet layer.  It works all fine but right now I have to click off the dialog to close it?  Is there something I can put in my `onSubmit` function? Should I do this outside of a dialog?

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Create a Layer</h1>
<div *ngIf="!arr">
<mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
</div>
<div *ngIf="arr">
<section>
<form class="form-style" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="20px" fxLayoutAlign="center center" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Zip Code (Optional)" ngModel name="zip">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Location (Optional)" ngModel name="location">
  </mat-form-field>
  <div class="radio" *ngFor="let gender of genders" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px">
    <label>
      <input type="radio"
      name="gender"
      [(ngModel)]="currentItem"
      [value]="gender">
    </label>
    {{ gender }}
  </div>
  Max Age <mat-slider thumbLabel
      [(ngModel)]="maxAge"
      name="maxAge"
      [min]="0"
      [max]="120"
  ></mat-slider>
  Min Age<mat-slider
      thumbLabel
      [(ngModel)]="minAge"
      name="minAge"
      [min]="0"
      [max]="120"
  ></mat-slider>
  <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="accent">Create Layer</button>
</form>
```

I have tried just using `mat-dialog-close` without the brackets and that closed it but the `ngForm` submit didn't work..  I plan on getting into reactive forms here soon but If there is an easier way to do it that way let me know! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

**A: close via submit handler:**

See [also this example](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/11/13/easy-dialogs-with-angular-material.html)

```
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submitForm()">
        ...
    </form>
</div>

public submitForm(): void {
    ...
    this.matDialogReference.close([]);
}
```

**B: close via click handler:**

See also [this complete example](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-dialog/)

```
<div mat-dialog-title>
    <h2 class="dialog-title">dialog title</h2>

    <a (click)="closeDialog()">
        <span class="icon-close"></span>
    </a>
</div>

<div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="closeDialog()">cancel</button>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="confirmDialog()">confirm</button>
</div>

public closeDialog(): void {
    this.matDialogReference.close([]);
}

public confirmDialog(): void {
    this.matDialogReference.close(this.form.value);
}
```

B closes the dialog when you click on close icon or the cancel button or the submit button.